# Security Question

Tags: sql-server, security

Hello guys I have a question

I have a group in that group a user shouldn't have syadmin permissions but he must be on that group.

He has his login map by the group and his windows login on sql server

Is it possible to deny him the server role syadmin but remain on the public role while still remain on the group?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can't deny a specific role, you just don't put them in that group. Straight answer to your question, nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a principal from `sysadmin` role does not remove the principal from `public` role. You cannot use `deny` on members of `sysadmin` role or the object owners. Using `sp_dropsrvrolemember` system stored procedure to remove the principal from `sysadmin` role should be your solution. If somebody does not belong to the party, better kick him out. Remember you need to be `sysadmin` yourself if you want to remove another principal from `sysadmin` role.

```
EXEC master..sp_dropsrvrolemember [user], 'sysadmin';
go
```

Comment: You can also be a member of securityadmin and modify membership of sysadmin role.

Comment: You are right. The `securityadmin` role should be treated as equivalent to the `sysadmin` role (Security Note from BOL). Thanks for pointing out.